# Separate group for contacts synced via CardDAV server in iOS address book

Tags: ios, contacts, webdav, addressbook

I'm working on a CardDAV server (based on SabreDAV) that will be used to synchronize contacts from only one group.

I successfully added my CardDAV account to the iOS settings. My CardDAV server adds one contact group to the address book. Now, I'd like to have only the contacts that belong to this group synced with my CardDAV server.

The behavior I observe is that all contacts that are added in the 'All contacts' group are also added to the CardDAV server. Is it possible to have only one specific group of contacts synced with the remote server?

There's a setting called 'Default Account' in the iOS contacts settings. It seems that iOS always adds contacts from the 'All contacts' group to the default server. Is it possible to have no 'Default Account', even when I have some accounts configured?

I also noticed that new groups that I add using GContact Lite also appear in my CardDAV server. I don't want the new groups to be added to my server. Should I just ignore the request on the server? What should be the HTTP response in this case?